# Make chrome put http:// in the browser

Tags: google-chrome

I'm working with a local server that spits out some XML. Whenever I go to change the url, say from `myserver.local:8080/servlet?p1=foo&p2=blah` to `myserver.local:8080/servlet?p1=foo&p2=otherblah` it tries to search google for "myserver.local:8080/servlet?p1=foo&p2=otherblah". I then remember I have to put http:// in the front, and THEN it knows to find it.

I don't want to disable google searching from the address bar, but how can I make it recognize that this is a server it can connect to without explicitly putting http:// in the bar every time. When you're debugging you're constantly changing parameters and it's annoying to make the same change over and over again.

Comment: I just tried to replicate but it works for me. What version of Chrome are you using? What method of entering the text into the bar are you using? Normally, I have the opposite issue with chrome. If I try to do a search for a file within chrome, it treats it as a web address due to the extension as opposed to doing a search for the filename.

Comment: If I enter `1rnvg91:8080/pallet?` it takes me to Google. If I enter `http://1rnvg91:8080/pallet?` it takes me to my server like it should.

Comment: I see. The issue here is that there doesn't seem to be a "." anywhere in your url. The way that the google search/http bar works is it searches your input for a period surrounded by alpha chars (no spaces), and if it finds one, will treat it as a domain (automatically put http://) Without the period surrounded by alpha, it thinks you're entering search terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Second possibility. If you're running off of windows, and the extra typing is slowing you down, check out [PhraseExpress](http://phraseexpress.com). Using this software, you can quite easily define a phrase that will automatically output http:// before your server links.

If you were copying and pasting, the phrase/macro content would look something like this: 
http://{#INSERTCLIPBOARD}

If you're manually typing it in, just remove everything after the second slash and add your choice address. Then all you have to do is set up a hotkey or autotext trigger to output the desired phrase.

The software seems daunting at first, but as someone who's been using it for a while, trust me, it's really useful, and will drastically cut back your workflow.

---ORIGINAL ANSWER BELOW---

If you're only working from one machine, you can edit the host file on your client machine/access terminal to make whatever url point to your server's IP address. For example, you can edit the host file to state that requests to "myserver.com" automatically go to a custom ip address that you define in the host file. You can then enter a link such as "myserver.com:8080/pallet?" into google, and it should redirect you accordingly.

if you're in a domain environment (in a corporate network, usually), you can enter the full domain name of your server (e.g. 1rnvg91.MyDomain:8080/pallet?). That should also work properly.

More info on editing the hosts file, in case you don't know: [enter link description here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29)

Comment: I had considered the hosts file before, but decided against it. Fully qualifing the server path appears to have fixed it. Unfortunate, but it will work for my testing purposes. Thanks!

Comment: In response to your edit, all I want to do is take a URL that already exists in the address bar, change the last couple letters on the end, and hit it again. Right now, If I go to a page with http://, the http:// disappears, meaning if I press enter a second time, I am taken to a different page. That's bad.

Comment: @corsiKa This can also be done. PhraseExpress has macro capabilities. You can also simulate keystrokes in addition to text. You can use hotkey/key combos to A) simulate an "End" keystroke, highglight a selection, and change it, and B), enter a simulated "Home" key, and automatically output "Http://", and then simulate pressing an "enter". All you would have to do is set up the correct phrases/keycombos. This software can also copy to/paste from the clipboard, as well as a TON of other things. Really helps to automate workflow. There's a bit of a learning curve, but worth it.

Comment: this post does not answer the question. it is like answering "how to install osx?" with "buy a new iMac and place it next to your pc"

Comment: No, it's not. First off, this is from 2012. Secondly, there is no way to force chrome to show the HTTP. Google turned it off and deliberately did not make it configurable. I provided a solution to alleviate the annoyance. If you need this question answered for your purposes, please re-ask the question with your specifics instead of reviving the long-dead.

Comment: Posts on this site are never long-dead; people are obviously still dealing with this issue 3+ years after the OP (me). Not going to complain though, the answer I'm looking for is to the question of why we cannot force chrome to show the HTTP :[. Onward I look...

Comment: This is doable via key combinations `Ctrl` + `L` and `Ctr` + `X` and `Ctrl` + `V` then `Enter` which will highlight the url bar, cut the address, paste the address back in prefixed with `http://` then load the page. Not a very nice way of getting around the problem, but better than executing a search when you hit enter. You could also try raising yet another bug to the chromium team to be added to the legion already merged into Issue 41467 to have the protocol restored or an option for users to decide how they want their url to look. Good luck with that while pkasting is on the chromium team.