# How to remove http:// adding in addressbar of google-chrome/firefox?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, user-interface

Chrome add the http:// when I copy address from addressbar, i often paste the address to console, to ping or ssh, it is possible to copy only hostname from addressbar ? How to switch off that feature in chrome and also in firefox ? I also like solution that will allow to unhide http:// in addressbar, so i can select domain without it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I am not sure you can force Google Chrome to stop prepending protocol when copying addresses from your addressbar, it seems that it is quite straightforward to actually force the browser to *display* that trimmed portion of the URL in the address bar, making it possible to copy just the domain or IP in question, without protocol being prepended. To do that, you need to **right-click the address bar and enable the "Always Show Full URLs" option.**

Comment: finally! they made this :)

Answer (score 21):

Bit of a hack as well, however I simply click in the toolbar, press the <kbd>Home</kbd> key, press <kbd>Space</kbd>, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

So basically, just add a <kbd>space</kbd> to the start. Most commands don't even care if you keep the <kbd>space</kbd> in the parameters.

Comment: I like this simple fix.

Comment: That's the workaround I use. Looking for a fix like the FireFox flag "browser.urlbar.trimURLs;false" but apparently Google knows better us what we should want in a browser.

Comment: Another thing crossed my mind last night, and I tried it this morning. Just click the address (omni) bar hold CTRL tap "XV" (or "AXV" if it does not fully highlight.) and the full URL will appear in the address bar so you can copy whatever you need out of it.

Answer (score 10):

If you want Firefox to permanently show `http` in the adress bar:

1. go to `about:config`
2. search for the option [`browser.urlbar.trimURLs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/Preference_reference/browser.urlbar.trimURLs)
3. set it to `false`

I don't use Chrome, but there is this question: [Make chrome put http:// in the browser](https://superuser.com/q/392476/151741)

Comment: I would kill for that feature in google chrome...

Comment: lol this should be added surely

Answer (score 7):

I use the following javascript snippet in Google Chrome to get the hostname and copy it to clipboard. I just tested it in Google Chrome.

You can create a bookmark int the Bookmarks Bar, name it `GetHostname` and paste the following javascript code into the "URL" part of the bookmark:

```js
javascript:(function(){
    function executeCopy(text) {
        var input = document.createElement('textarea');
        document.body.appendChild(input);
        input.value = text;
        input.select();
        document.execCommand('Copy');
        input.remove();
    }
    executeCopy(window.location.hostname);
})();
```

Comment: Nice solution, but `input.focus()` causes the page to scroll to the bottom. It's unnecessary, at least for me - the text gets copied without it.

Comment: fantastic!!! This is a really nice quick fix

Answer (score 5):

Warning: Total hack response…

If you highlight the left-most character of the domain name, Chrome automatically adds on the `http://` because its implicit in the address.  If you highlight and copy all but the first character, you don't get that issue (and need to re-add it in the command).

However as hacks go, I find it easier to do the above (highlight, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, terminal, type first char, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) than to remove the `http://` myself.

Others may have better solutions.

Comment: I using the same trick, but it ugly, i just found myself  today in terrible user environment, so got several questions that i collected last 2-3 years :)

Comment: @eicto: Make a list of links to these questions and open a google chrome issue/feature request: http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95315

Comment: @NickSoft - FWIW, people have been complaining since this was checked in (well over 3 years ago) to no avail, so I'm not sure 1 more will make a difference.  It's an interest read, though: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=41467

Comment: Yes, I know. However most people do not take actions. One more is not a big deal, but many more is. I guess google measure in %. If most of the people do not complain, then they are ok with it. I guess most people think that they won't make a difference and that's why they don't complain.

Answer (score 5):

This is pretty awful that chrome needs it, but you can use this addon to copy the host by clicking a button: http://chrisiona.com/post/122938597943/hostcopy-google-chrome-extension

Comment: I wonder how many people have coded a workaround to the problems caused by the chrome dev team removing the protocol from the url bar and putting in the crappy insert-http-when-copying code. They must have absolutely no knowledge of automated testing if they thought this was a good idea.

Comment: @Underverse probably lots. But then again, Google has legendarily bad UX design, so it shouldn't be surprising.

Answer (score 4):

Where is the answer?
The suggestion with Home button doesn't work anymore.

While reading all not working answers (I don't need host? for what? if people copy url, they need full url..:), I made my own solution.
Just click to address bar, then hold "Ctrl+Shift", then click "Right" and "Left",
Voila.
Then you can "Ctrl"+"C"...

Comment: btw, good idea,

Comment: and what if i want to copy with my cursor?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome 83 will be adding the flag
**chrome://flags/#omnibox-context-menu-show-full-urls**

> 1. Go to `chrome://flags/#omnibox-context-menu-show-full-urls` .
> 2. Click the drop-down menu on the right side of the flag to select 'Enabled'
> 3. Restart the web browser.

Sources:

- [Google Chrome Adding Option to Always Show Full URLs](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/google/google-chrome-adding-option-to-always-show-full-urls/)
- [Chrome Canary now Always Shows FULL URLs if you enable this Flag](https://techdows.com/2020/03/chrome-canary-now-always-shows-full-urls-if-you-enable-this-flag.html)
- [The omnibox context menu should provide an option that will prevent URL elisions for the entire Chrome profile.](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1061576)

Comment: has anyone found this flag? Currently running chrom v98 and i cannot locate this flag.

Comment: yes, seems they removed it "you not need this" :)