# It's a constant annoyance that Google Chrome Inserts http(s):// when copying URLs From Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, copy-paste, url

It's a constant annoyance that Google Chrome Inserts `http(s)://` when copying URLs from Chrome. As a network systems engineer, I am constantly copying URLs to **network devices** from Chrome into PuTTY, another shell or a script or command line. Is there a workaround or fix?

Comment: But the http(s):// prefix is a normal part of the URL? Could you clarify what you're trying to copy -- the entire URL or only its domain name?

Comment: @grawity if you want to copy just the hostname for `theserver:8080` you select `theserver` and when you paste say after `ping` in a command line you get `ping http://theserver`

Comment: What is the problem? If you are using something like `curl` in the command line you need that `http(s)://` in there. Maybe you need to edit your question to better explain what you are doing with these URLs in PuTTY?

Comment: @hidralisk What you describe makes no sense. Coping a URL from Chrome will naturally have `http(s)://`. It’s not as if this stuff is designed to strip that off so `ping` works well.

Comment: @hidralisk Doesn't happen here -- if I don't select 'http://', then I don't get 'http://' copied... In your case, is it that Chromium _hides_ the original 'http://' in the URL bar? (It used to do so while displaying the URL, but IIRC even then it used to behave normally while editing.)

Comment: @JakeGould Chrome hides http:// from the URL edit box. When I select something in **any** edit box, the convention is to get in the clipboard exactly what I selected. For example, if in my previous example I select `theserver:` (note the column), i will get exactly that in the clipboard. But, if i copy the hostname Chrome thinks it knows better and injects http:// in front of the string that goes into the clipboard.

Comment: @hidralisk Chrome—and many other browsers such as Safari and Opera—hide the protocol part of the URL for aesthetic and user experience reasons. This is a very modern change in behavior. I believe that Firefox is the only browser that still reveals the protocol in the URL area of the browser. So there is a UX point to be made here, but in the end I think the issue is browsers hiding the protocol in the URL area (called the “omnibox” due to it’s multiple uses nowadays) not that the protocol gets copied with the URL.

Comment: WOW this is a duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/503436/how-to-remove-http-adding-in-addressbar-of-google-chrome-firefox

Comment: I did. Thanks.I am constantly copying URLs to **network devices** from Chrome into PuTTY

Answer (score 1):

Visit `chrome://flags/#omnibox-ui-hide-steady-state-url-scheme` and set the experiment "Omnibox UI Hide Steady-State URL Scheme" to "Disabled". This should return the address bar to a more traditional mode, where the scheme prefix is always shown, and copying will grab exactly what was selected.

While you're at it, you can disable all other "hide steady-state *etc*" experiments (even if they're currently inactive on your system), so that they won't get activated for testing in the future.

Comment: did this work for anyone? on my chrome ver 74 this did not have effect, i did relaunch.